# Open an HTTP-connection to the "final" (non-redirected) URL

Tags: java, http, httpurlconnection, http-redirect, http-response-codes

**Given a URL string, I want to get an HTTP-connection to the "final" (non-redirected) URL:**

- If the response-code is 2xx, then I can simply use the initial connection.
- If the response-code is 3xx, then I need to open a new connection and try again.
- For any other response-code (such as 4xx or 5xx), I "give up" and return `null`.

**My code is given below:**

```
HttpURLConnection getConnection(String url) throws Exception
{
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
    while (true)
    {
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","");
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        switch (responseCode/100)
        {
        case 2:
            return connection;
        case 3:
            switch (responseCode)
            {
            case 300:
                connection = ???
                break;
            case 301:
            case 302:
            case 303:
            case 305:
            case 307:
                connection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(connection.getHeaderField("Location")).openConnection();
                break;
            case 304:
                connection = ???
                break;
            default:
                return null;
            }
            break;
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**My questions are hereby:**

1. How should I handle response-codes 300 and 304?
2. Am I handling response-codes 301, 302, 303, 305 and 307 correctly?

**Any other constructive comments on the method above will also be appreciated.**

Thanks

Comment: All codes are defined in here http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html and are quite well explained, but not all might make sense in your situation. The question is, why do you want to deal with them all?

Comment: Because I receive them all in the response-codes of different URLs!!!

Comment: 300 to 307 seem to make sense, but why not simply try them? I have no idea what you are connecting to and what you are sending. For instance why do you get 304 returned? According to doc it says: "If the client has performed a conditional GET request and access is allowed", what did you send to the server?

Comment: It's strange that you receive the 304 error. If I am not wrong, it's used in pair with other headers like "if_modified_since" and its purpose is to avoid multiple http requests if the client that generated the request already have an updated version of the doc in its cache. You should check if the "if_modified_since" is set in your header request. If you not need to handle a cache you can avoid  this header and you'll never receive a 304 code

Comment: Thanks dendini. Well, I admit I never received a 304, but would like to be prepared for this case. Is it not a feasible scenario when performing a "normal" URL GET request?

Comment: Thank you nax83. So I will get 304 only if the web-page of some specific URL is already in my cache? If I set `no-cache` in the request, will it guarantee that I never get a 304?

Comment: You should probably close the connections before you open new ones.

Comment: What, using `disconnect`? According to the documentation, it is not supposed to have any effect. Am I wrong?

Comment: Since you're doing `connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);` are you sure you need all the logic here, at least to handle the 3xx codes ? The HttpURLConnection does this automatically.

Comment: Out of "empiric" experience - yes, I'm sure. I often get 3xx responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although all of these are some kind of redirects, it's tricky to come up with a model to handle them all.

You may want to read http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-26.html#rfc.section.6.4 for more information.